# what is best way to do analysis over database table of million records?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

I have a csv file of 50 mn records and I would like to deal with it using pandas. While I am loading it into data frame my system is getting hung. Any thoughts would be great help?

Comment: Using chunk process it chunk by chunk also implement your analysis in it within the chunk

Comment: thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2):

Read the csv and store it in a SQLite in-memory database.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine # database connection
import datetime as dt
disk_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///311_8M.db') # Initializes database with filename 311_8M.db in current directory
start = dt.datetime.now()
chunksize = 20000
j = 0
index_start = 1

for df in pd.read_csv('big.csv', chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True, encoding='utf-8'):

    df = df.rename(columns={c: c.replace(' ', '') for c in df.columns}) # Remove spaces from columns

    df['CreatedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CreatedDate']) # Convert to datetimes
    df['ClosedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ClosedDate'])

    df.index += index_start

    # Remove the un-interesting columns
    columns = ['Agency', 'CreatedDate', 'ClosedDate', 'ComplaintType', 'Descriptor',
               'CreatedDate', 'ClosedDate', 'TimeToCompletion',
               'City']

    for c in df.columns:
        if c not in columns:
            df = df.drop(c, axis=1)    


    j+=1
    print '{} seconds: completed {} rows'.format((dt.datetime.now() - start).seconds, j*chunksize)

    df.to_sql('data', disk_engine, if_exists='append')
    index_start = df.index[-1] + 1

df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM data LIMIT 3', disk_engine)
```

You can then query whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks, you can do your own research too!